# Access parent query values in subquery containing variables

Tags: mysql, subquery

I've done quite a bit of looking around on this and would like to exhaust all possibilities before we take a different tack.

The following query:

```
SELECT 
    node.nid AS nid
FROM
    node node
WHERE
    (node.type in ('new_catalog_master')) 
AND (SELECT 
        status
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            @COST := (SELECT 
                    pm.field_price_matrix_ppu_value
                FROM
                    node n
                INNER JOIN content_type_new_catalog_master ncm ON ncm.nid = n.nid
                INNER JOIN content_type_vendor_price_object vpo ON vpo.field_vpo_product_ref_nid = ncm.nid
                INNER JOIN content_type_price_matrix pm ON pm.nid = vpo.nid
                WHERE
                    ncm.nid = node.nid AND vpo.field_vpo_pref_vendor_value = 'yes' AND pm.field_price_matrix_quantity_value = (SELECT 
                        MAX(ctpm.field_price_matrix_quantity_value)
                    FROM
                        content_type_price_matrix ctpm
                    WHERE
                        ctpm.nid = vpo.nid)),
                @DATA_MARGIN := (SELECT 
                    cs.low
                FROM
                    competitor_stats cs
                WHERE
                    cs.nid = node.nid),
                @SUGGESTED_MARGIN := (1-(@COST/@DATA_MARGIN))*100,
                @MARGIN := (SELECT 
                    ctfmm.field_margin_matrix_gross_margin_value, ctfmm.field_margin_matrix_role_value 
                FROM
                    content_type_flexi_margin_matrix ctfmm
                WHERE
                    ctfmm.nid = node.nid AND ctfmm.field_margin_matrix_role_value = 1),
                @MARGIN_MAX := 5/100,
                (ABS(@SUGGESTED_MARGIN-@MARGIN) > @SUGGESTED_MARGIN*@MARGIN_MAX) AS status
        ) as result);
```

Returns:

```
Unknown column 'node.nid' in 'where clause'
```

If we hardcode in a nid value into the subqueries, the query returns a value. Is it possible to access node.nid in the subqueries?

We kind of need to keep the subqueries in the WHERE clause due to certain contraints.

Comment: try to use nid instead of node.nid, in your first select you have `node.nid AS nid`

Comment: Hi, gave that a go, and I get `Column nid in where clause is ambiguous`

Comment: try with ` node.nid AS node_nid`, and whenever you have `node.nid` change it for `node_nid`

Comment: hmm...`Unknown column 'node_nid' in 'where clause'`